# Trying to read data from a text file, make a struct from it, and print the fields to stdout

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, fgets

I seem to have no problems reading from the file and then creating the struct, but printing the struct gives me a segmentation fault.

Employee definition

```
struct _Employee {
  int salary; // Monthly salary in UK pounds sterling
  char *name; // Pointer to character string holding name of employee.
  char* department;           // MUST be dynamically allocated from the heap.
};

typedef struct _Employee Employee;
```

Function to read from a file

```
Employee* readfile(FILE* file) {
  Employee* newemployee;
  newemployee = malloc(sizeof(Employee));
  char tempsalary[10];
  int salary;
  char name[20];
  char dept[20];
  char* names = malloc(sizeof(name));
  char* depts = malloc(sizeof(dept));
  char* status; // Returned by fgets(). Will be NULL at EOF


    status = fgets(names, sizeof(name), file);
    if (status == NULL)
      return NULL;
    else {
      newemployee->name = strdup(status);


    fgets(tempsalary, sizeof(name), file);
    sscanf(tempsalary, "%d", &salary);
    newemployee->salary = salary;

    fgets(depts, sizeof(dept), file);
    newemployee->department = strdup(depts);

    return newemployee;
    }
}
```

Function to print the struct generated by readfile.

```
void printEmployee(Employee *employee) {
      fprintf(stdout, "Name = %sSalary = %d\nDepartment = %s\n\n", // SEGFAULT HERE
          employee->name, employee->salary, employee->department);
}
```

Main program

```
int main() {
  FILE* file;
  file = fopen ("stest2.txt", "r");
  Employee* employees[max_employees];
  int i;
  int c;
  Employee* temp;

    for (i = 0; i < max_employees; i++) {
    employees[i] = readfile(file)   
    printEmployee(employees[i]);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: please show an Employee type definition.

Comment: I added it to the top of the code.

Comment: still looking, but you're telling fgets() that tempsalary can hold 20 bytes, even though it can only hold 10.

Comment: Okay, I fixed that but I still get a seg fault.

Comment: oleg_g FTW: you're still printing out employees even after readfile() returns null. <head slap>

Comment: Okay, I've tried many different ways of handling this but have not found a way that works. I'm thinking I have to test if the first field in the struct is NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

readfile() can return NULL in case of fgets error. This case is not handled in main.
As a primitive suggestion:

```
    for (i = 0; i < max_employees; i++) {
        employees[i] = readfile(file);
        if(NULL != employees[i])
        {   
            printEmployee(employees[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error reading file");
        }
```

Comment: How should I go about handling this in the main?

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to go with fgets() scribbling on the stack. Change this:

```
 fgets(tempsalary, sizeof(name), file);
```

to this:

```
 fgets(tempsalary, sizeof(tempsalary), file);
```

Might not be the problem, but it's certainly "a" problem.

Comment: When I debug in gdb, i get this error:

    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0x0000000000400868 in printEmployee (employee=0x0).

Comment: if (status == NULL)
      return NULL; <--- this a case. you do not handle this in main